# Mustache template with unknown properties name

Tags: javascript, mustache

Is it possible to template an array of object with unknown property?

```
var objs: [{
  propA: 'A',
  propB: 'B',
  propC: 'A',
  propD: 'B'
}];
```

And the template could be:

```
<ul>
  <li>{{property_name}}: {{property_value}}</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

you first should define an array of objects the proper way:

```
var myarray=[{propA:'valueA'},{propB:'valueB'}]
```

then refer to each object by index or any iteration method

```
<ul>
  <li>{{Object.keys(myarray[0])}}:{{myarray[0]['propA']}}</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's something to give you an idea on how to get the keys and values:

HTML

```
<script type="text/html" id="tmpl">
    {{#objs}}

         <div>
         {{key}}: {{value}}
        </div>

    {{/objs}}
</script>
```

JavaScript

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var output = $("#output");
    var template = $("#tmpl").html();

    var objs = [{
        propA: 'A',
        propB: 'B',
        propC: 'C',
        propD: 'D'
    }];

    var mustacheFormattedData = {
        'objs': []
    };

    for (var prop in objs[0]) {
        if (objs[0].hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
            mustacheFormattedData['objs'].push({
                'key': prop,
                    'value': objs[0][prop]
            });
        }
    }

    var html = Mustache.render(template, mustacheFormattedData);
    output.append(html);

});
```

**Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/moogs/qK5NT/83/**